# How to return View from action when the request is always asynchronous

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action with the following definition in MVC:

```
 public ActionResult Create(Club club)
    {       
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Club clubFound = db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClubName == club.ClubName);

            if (clubFound != null)
            {
                ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName), "CountryID", "CountryName");
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The club already exists in the database.");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                db.Clubs.Add(club);
                db.SaveChanges();
                string message = MvcHtmlString.Create(@"Club added to the db successfully. <a href=""/"">Go back to home page.</a>").ToString();
                //TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Club successfully added.";
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        return View();           
    }
```

If all the data is fine, the method executes successfully and everything is OK. But when there is a model error and the action returns View it actially returns at within the view so I have one view in another. My question is how to normally return the view with all the errors like in a normal POST request? The data coming from the view is always from an Ajax form so the request is always asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should just return the model and return to the same view the action was triggered. As you're adding an error to the model, it have to return to the view, also I guess you might have to add a `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to your view.

Something like:

```
public ActionResult Create(Club club)
{       
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Club clubFound = db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClubName == club.ClubName);

        if (clubFound != null)
        {
            ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName), "CountryID", "CountryName");
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The club already exists in the database.");
            return View(club);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Clubs.Add(club);
            db.SaveChanges();
            string message = MvcHtmlString.Create(@"Club added to the db successfully. <a href=""/"">Go back to home page.</a>").ToString();
            //TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Club successfully added.";
            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    return View(club);           
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the club object in the View() function but the result is the same - a whole new view in the view itself bug. Otherwise, I had Html.ValidationSummary() in the view.